# Stuck on put player in the board

Tags: c

I am doing a game in C, I have a board with dimensions generated by the user, where the Xs are the randomly generated 'trees', I am trying to enter the players J1 and J2 who would be who are going to play, I want it in opposite corners, for example if the board is 9x9, J1 should be at 9a and J2 at 1i.

I tried putting  `tablero[i = TamTablero] [j = 0] = 'J1'` in the code, but that didn't work. And the same for J2. I've been stuck here for quite a while.

Here is my code, where TamTablero means BoardSize:

````
int main() {

    int TamTablero=0;

    printf("Ingrese el area del bosque donde va a jugar: ");
    scanf("%d", &TamTablero);

    char tablero[TamTablero][TamTablero];

    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < TamTablero; i++)
       for(j = 0; j < TamTablero; j++)
           tablero[i][j] = '*';

    srand (time(NULL));

    int arboles = 0;

    while(arboles < TamTablero + 3){

       i = rand() % TamTablero;
       j = rand() % TamTablero;

       if( tablero[i][j] != 'X'){

            tablero[i][j] = 'X';
            arboles++;
       }
    }

    printf("\n   ");

    for (j=0; j<TamTablero; j++)

        printf(" %c", 'A' + j);

        printf("\n");

    for (i=0; i<TamTablero; i++){

        printf("%d |", i+1);

        for (j=0; j<TamTablero; j++){

            printf(" %c", tablero[i][j]);
       }

        printf(" \n");
   }

 return 0;

} ```
````

Answer (score 3):

You can add the players when you're creating the board:

```c
for(i = 0; i < TamTablero; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < TamTablero; j++) {
        // Add J1
        if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            tablero[i][j] = '1';    // Player 1
        else if (i == TamTablero - 1 && j == TamTablero - 1)
            tablero[i][j] = '2';    // Player 2
        else
            tablero[i][j] = '*';    // void
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had not thought of it that way, that you could enter the players at the same time that you started the board. Now it's time to make them move through it! Your comment was of great help to me. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean single quotes instead of double ?

Comment: @alex01011 You're correct, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `tablero` as an array of characters, in particular *single* characters. If you want to do `tablero[i][j] = "J1"`, you will have to declare `tablero` as an array of *strings*, or `char *` in C.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had not realized that detail and it will help me a lot to move forward.